# Dynamically created form called via onclick disappears immediately Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick, element, division

I have dynamically created a button in my Javascript function  and called another function onclick, as shown below.

```
streambtn =  document.createElement("button");
streambtn.setAttribute("onclick","createattribute()");
```

The createattribute() method opens a subdivision within the dynamically created form and this function is as follows.

```
function createattribute() {

        inputval.innerHTML = "Provide a Stream name and click to add attribute-type pairs to yours stream.";
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.placeholder="Attribute name";
        input.id="attr"+attrID;
        input.className = "attr-textfield-style";
        inputval.appendChild(input);

        //Display the drop down menu

        var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
        var html = '<select>', attrtypes = typeGenerate(), i;
        for(i = 0; i < attrtypes.length; i++) {
            html += "<option value='"+attrtypes[i]+"'>"+attrtypes[i]+"</option>";
        }
        html += '</select>';
        newDiv.className="attr-combobox-style";
        newDiv.id="type"+attrID;
        newDiv.innerHTML= html;
        inputval.appendChild(newDiv);
        attrID++;

        alert("attrname id: "+input.id+" attrtype id: "+ newDiv.id);
    }
```

The inputval is a division within the dynamically created form where the newly created form elements from the createattribute() function will be appended to. But the issue that I'm facing right now, is that though the method is correctly called, the form(dynamically created form) immediately disappears in a split second once the streambtn is clicked. Once it is clicked, it displays the first line "Provide a Stream name and click to add attribute-type pairs to yours stream." in a flash and disappears. Is there a way to keep it onscreen and then hide it depending on any conditions(like after the user finishes entering the data corresponding to that newly opened form-> created via createattribute() method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add `type = "button"` as `<button>` without `type = "button"` will act as submit button and over `click` of the `submit` buttopn, page will be unloaded.

```
streambtn =  document.createElement("button");
streambtn.type = 'button';
streambtn.setAttribute("onclick","createattribute()");
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This worked. Though I did figure out that the form was being submitted on the button click, I had no idea that I had to declare the type separately since it was specified in the createElement("button") line.

Comment: @NayantaraWilfred Even if it is button tag, you are suppose to define type to prevent form submission on click event...